# -= Operator, confused with output result

Tags: actionscript-3, operators, flashdevelop

I was recently tracing a line of code:

```
x -= 353 - 350
```

However, the answer came up to be -3.

To my surprise, I figure the -= operator would follow as:

```
x = x - 353 - 350
```

which then would equal to `-703`

Why is the actual answer `-3` and not `-703`?

I was searching for reference on this website:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/operators.html

The example it gave led me to believe that the operator -= should produce -703.

```
var x:uint = 5; x -= 5; // x is now 0
```

Wouldn't the above example represent how `x = x - 5` is `0`? Or is there an alternative code/logic that I'm missing?

Comment: did my answer help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Operator precendece:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

`-=` has precedence of `3`, while `+` and `-` have precedence 13 (higher),

so the code executes as the equivalent of

```
x -= (353 - 350)
x -= (3)
x -= 3;
x = x - 3;
```

And as per basic mathematics:

```
x -= (353 - 350)
x += -(353 - 350)
x += (-353 + 350)
x += (-3);
```

Comment: I still don't get it though because if we were to apply the same logic to this example:

var x:uint = 5; x -= 5; // x is now 0

That would turn out to be:

x -= 5

Comment: Sorry for double post, accidentally hit enter before finishing.

I still don't get it though because if we were to apply the same logic to this example: 

var x:uint = 5; x -= 5; // x is now 0 

That would turn out to be: 

x -= 5
x = x - 5
x = -5

x should be 0 according to the answer of the source I linked in the original post but I'll type out the link on this post here as well:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/operators.html

"Subtraction assignment : Assigns expression1 the value of expression1 - expression2"

Comment: why if x = 5 => x -= 5 <==> x = 5 - 5 <==> 0

Comment: `x-=5` is `x = x - 5`, but remember that the left-hand side is just there for ASSIGNMENT. this isn't a real equation. `x = x - 5` executes the `x-5` portion, and then assigns the RESULT to the left-hand X. the left-hand X is there purely as a writing destination, and is never read-from. the right-hand x, similarly, is there only as a data SOURCE, and is never written to. so `x-=5` executes as `x=x-5` -> `x=5-5` -> `x=0`, and your `x` var now contains `0`.

Answer (score 4):

I've tested it in Python. It appears to be just basic arithmetics..

Assuming `x` is currently `zero`

`x -= 353 - 350` which is equal to saying `x = x - (353 - 350)`. 
Get the result of brackets first then equation is simply `x = 0 - 3` which gives result : `-3`

Answer (score 2):

Daniel and Marc are right.

You use the wrong operator :
To get -703 you should use -= like this

```
var x:int = 0;
x -= 353 + 350;
// x -= (353 + 350); 
// So => x -= 703
trace(x); //output -703
```

Because

```
x -= 353 - 350;
```

Means x -= 3;
Same logic.